# Keeping getting an error of Const PCB cannot convert to *PCB

Tags: c++, process, priority-queue

I am getting an error that says const PCB cannot convert to *PCB and the only way i can declare an object to be NULL is with pointer. Can anyone help me figure out the problem. i put // where the error is happening I'm just trying to store the highest priority Process Control block in the CPU for the first "if statement when it is NULL or empty" and the 2nd compares the top of the priority queue to the cpu and preemptive it if the ready_queue.top is higher than cpu. Have tried using bool isEmpty() and other thing but nothing seems to work

```
struct PrCB
{
    int PrID;
    int PrSize;
    int prior;
    int sumMem= 0;
    bool operator < (const PrCB & a)
    {
        return prior < a.prior;
    }
    bool operator > (const PrCB & a)
    {
        return prior > a.prior;
    }
};

struct compare
{
    bool operator()(const PrCB &a,const PrCB &b)
    {
        return a.prior < b.prior;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int pid = 0;
    char inter;
    PrCB pcb;
    PrCB cpu;
    priority_queue<PrCB, vector<PrCB>,compare> ready_queue;
    while(true)
    {
        cin >> inter;
        if(inter == 'N')
        {
            pcb.PrID = pid;
            cout << "How much memory space?" << endl;
            cin >> pcb.PrSize;
            cout << "What is the Priority?" << endl;
            cin >> pcb.prior;
            ready_queue.push(pcb);
            pid++;
            //if(cpu == NULL)
            {
                cpu == ready_queue.top();
                ready_queue.pop();
            }
            //if(cpu < ready_queue.top())
            {
                ready_queue.push(cpu);
                //cpu = ready_queue.top();
                ready_queue.pop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix several things with your code and then this will be more clear:

1. In your `operator()` overload change `PrCBk` to `PrCB`.
2. In your while loop change `While` to `while`.
3. You do not have `operator==` defined and this is causing errors whenever you use the `==` operator on things like `cpu`.
4. Be sure to include operator overloads for different data types; i.e. pointers vs. references.
5. Look at return values for functions like `priority_queue.top()` and compare `const_reference` to pointer. Make sure you are using these correctly.

These things need to be corrected so your code compiles. There are other syntax errors as well that need to be corrected.

Comment: so if i were to make a bool operator == ( PrCB &a )    if (a.priority == NULL) return something?    and i dont understand what you mean by priority_queue.top() or did u mean ready_queue.top()? thanks for the help !

Comment: `a.priority` is of type `int` which means you don't need to check `NULL`. I think you may be confused about what is a pointer and what is not, `int` is not a pointer. `ready_queue` is of type `priority_queue`, so yes you can read it as `ready_queue.top()`.

Comment: ahhh okay so if we make the bool operator ==(PrCB &a)   what is that suppose to return  cause i want to use an if(cpu == empty or NULL) move ready_queue.top() to cpu which is what im having trouble with :S

Comment: You don't need the `bool` operator if you're not going to use `*cpu == ready_queue.top()`. I misread the line where you have `cpu == ready_queue.top()` which is the wrong use of `==`. Also, use `if (cpu == nullptr)` instead of empty or `NULL`.